# Visualizer on multiple monitors

Tags: itunes, windows

I have a windows 7 PC with multiple monitors.

It is possible to display the ITunes visualizer across multiple monitors?

It currently only uses the one that I am on.

Comment: I noticed that this question is tagged with the "Windows-7" tag. Do you want to do this in iTunes for Windows, or iTunes for Mac?

Comment: @ChrisMukherjee, this is about iTunes on Windows-7

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the only way to have the iTunes visualizer display across multiple monitors is to configure your other monitors to duplicate the display of the monitor where the visualizer is currently being displayed.

Here's a sample screenshot of where that option might be located in your Control Panel:
[image: Control Panel > Screen Resolution]

Comment: Keep in mind that this is more of a work-around than a solution